# Entity Framework Validation & usage

Tags: entity-framework, validation

I'm aware there is an AssociationChanged event, however, this event fires after the association is made. There is no AssociationChanging event.  So, if I want to throw an exception for some validation reason, how do I do this and get back to my original value?

Also, I would like to default values  for my entity based on information from other entities **but do this only when I know the entitiy is instanced for insertion into the database**.   How do I tell the difference between that and the object getting instanced because it is about to be populated based on existing data?   Am I supposed to know?   Is that considiered business logic that should be outside of my entity business logic?

If that's the case, then should I be designing controller classes to wrap all these entities?   My concern is that if I deliver back an entity, I want the client to get access to the properties, but I want to retain tight control over validations on how they are set, defaulted, etc. Every example I've seen references context, which is outside of my enity partial class validation, right?

BTW, I looked at the EFPocoAdapter and for the life of me cannot determine how to populate lists of  from within my POCO class... anyone know how I get to the context from a EFPoco Class?

Answer (score 2):

This is in reply to a comment I left.  Hopefully this answers your question, Shimmy.  Just comment, and I will shorten it or remove it if it doesn't answer your question.

You will need both INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces to be implemented on your class (unless it is something like an entity framework object, which I believe implements these internally).

And before you set a value to this property, you will need to raise NotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging event, using the name of the property in PropertyChangingEventArgs constructor.

And after you set this value you need to raise NofityPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event, again using the name of the property this is being raised in PropertyChangedEventArgs constructor.

Then you have to handle the PropertyChanging and PropertyChanged events.  In the PropertyChanging event, you need to cache the value.  In the PropertyChanged event, you can compare and throw an exception.

To get the property from PropertyChanging/PropertyChanged event args, you need to use relfection.

```
// PropertyName is the key, and the PropertyValue is the value.
Dictionary <string, object> propertyDict = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    // Convert this function prototype to C# from VBNet.  I like how Handles is descriptive.
    Public Sub PropertyChanging(sender As object, e As PropertyChangingEventArgs) Handles Foo.PropertyChanging
    {
      if (sender == null || preventRecursion)
      {
        return;
      } // End if

      Type senderType = sender.GetType();
      PropertyInfo info = senderType.GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
      object propertyValue = info.GetValue(sender, null);

      // Change this so it checks if e.PropertyName already exists.
      propertyDict.Add(e.PropertyName, propertyValue);
    } // End PropertyChanging() Event

     // Convert this function prototype to C# from VBNet.  I like how Handles is descriptive.
    Public Sub PropertyChanged(sender As object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Foo.PropertyChanged
    {
      if (sender == null || preventRecursion)
      {
        return;
      } // End if

      Type senderType = sender.GetType();
      PropertyInfo info = senderType.GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
      object propertyValue = info.GetValue(sender, null);

      // Change this so it makes sure e.PropertyName exists.
      object oldValue = propertyDict(e.PropertyName);
      object newValue = propertyValue;

      // No longer needed.
      propertyDict.Remove(e.PropertyName);

      if (/* some condition */)
      {
        try {
          preventRecursion = true;
          info.SetValue(oldValue, null);
          Throw New Exception();
        } finally {
          preventRecursion = false;
        } // End try
      } // End if
    } // End PropertyChanging() Event
```

Notice how I am using PreventRecursion, which is a boolean I forgot to add above these methods?  When you reset the property back to its previous value, these events will be recalled.

tl;dr

Now you could derive a single event which inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged, but uses an argument which holds an Object representing the previous value as well as the Property Name.  And that would reduce the number of events being fired down to one, have similar functionality, and have backwards compatibility with INotifyPropertyChanged.

But if you want to handle anything before the property gets set (say the property does an irreversible change or you need to setup other properties before setting that variable, otherwise an exception will be thrown) you won't be able to do that.

Overall, this method is a very old way of doing things.  I would take Poker Villian's answer and have invalid data able to be entered.  But disallow saving to a database.

Entity Framework has some excellent code towards validation.  You add validation to your properties via attributes.  And then it takes care of the work of processing those attributes.  Then you can make a property called IsValid, which calls Entity Framework specific validation.  It also distinguishes both field errors (like typing in the wrong characters or having a string too long), and class errors (like having missing data or conflicting keys).

Then you can bind IsValid to controls validation, and they will display a red bubble while invalid data is entered.  Or you could just implement IsValid validation yourself.  But If IsValid is false, SaveChanges event would need to cancel saving.

btw.  The code provided will not compile and is pseudocode only (mixing vb and c#).  But I believe it is much more descriptive than c# alone--showing exactly what is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question, I would simply implement the changes to the associations as business logic. For example, if you add a Teacher class with multiple Student, do not add students like

```
aTeacher.Students.Add(new Student)
```

instead, create a AddStudent method

```
public Student AddNewStudent(string name, string studentID)
{

    Student s = new Student( name, studentID);
    s.Teacher = this; // changes the association
    return s;
}
```

That way you have full control on when associations are changed. Of course that what prevents another programmer from adding a student directly? On the Student side, you can set the Teacher setter to private (and change the constructor to accept a teacher or similar). On the teacher side, how to make the Students collection non-insertable? I'm not certain... maybe transforming it in a custom collection that doesn't accept inserts.

Concerning the second part of your question, you could probably use the OnVarNameChanging events. If the EntityState is 'New' then you can apply your logic that fetches the real values.

There is also an event that fires when you save changes (OnSavingChanges?) that you could use to determine which objects are new and set some values.

But maybe the simplest solution is to always set the defaults in the constructor and they will get overwritten if the data is loaded from the DB.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory that produces instances for you depending on your need like:

```
getStudent(String studentName, long studentId, Teacher teacher) {
    return new Student(studentName, studentId);
}

getStudentForDBInseration(String studentName, long studentId, Teacher teacher) {
    Student student = getStudent(studentName, studentId);
    student = teacher;
    //some entity frameworks need the student to be in the teachers student list
    //so you might need to add the student to the teachers student list
    teacher.addStudent(student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a serious lack not having an AssociationChanging (that inherits from [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx)) event.

It bothers me also very much, therefore I reported this to Microsoft Connect **[Please vote here!](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1058879-associationchanging-event)**

And BTW, I also think this is also stupid that the PropertyChangingEventArgs doesn't inherit CancelEventArgs, since cancelling with an exception is not always the elegant solution, besides, throwing exceptions cost more performance than calling the OnPropertyChangingEvent then check for the returned e.Cancel, so does it cost less than raising the PropertyChangingEvent, which you anyway call them both.
Also an exception can be thrown at the handler anyway instead of marking e.Cancel as true, for those who insist to go the Exception way. **[Vote Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/580994/propertychangingeventargs-class-should-inherit-from-canceleventargs)**.

Comment: PropertyChangingEventArgs has no relation to CancelEventArgs.  They have times they need to be used exclusively for different purposes.  To force inheritance would cause unneeded complication and frustration (tightly coupling them together).  There is PropertyChangingEvent and PropertyChangedEvent, and I believe they satisfy the functionality you desire without changes being made to them (not to mention, that would break .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0 compatibility).

Comment: @TamusJRoyce, OK, I agree, it should not inherit from `CancelEventArgs`, but what it should do is my other request which is provide the candidate value (which the easy way to get it is by getting current method attributes with a significant amount of performance cost).

Answer (score 0):

To maybe answer part of your question or expound on ADB's answer you can user ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry to find the state of the entities and write your custom default logic.

SaveChanges is the method on the context that you can use, or SavingChanges is the event that occurs before SaveChanges is called.

You can override SaveChanges and only call base.SaveChanges if you don't want to abort the change

There is also a ObjectMaterialized event for the context.

Between the two you can stick all your validation and creation code in one location, which may be appropriate if they are complex and include values of other objects etc..